# Limit of multivariable function: approach from x and y axis not the same

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to find the limit of the function
$$ f(x,y)=\frac{1}{x}\sin\frac{xy^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} $$
for $(x,y)$ approaching $(0,0)$. Based on the $\frac{1}{x}$ I am expecting for the limit to not exist. So I have tried to approach along the different axes.

For the approach along the $x$-axis, I get a limit value of $0$.

However, when I approach along the $y$-axis, I end up with the following limit:
$$ \lim_{y\to0} (\frac{1}{0}\sin(0y))$$ I am inclined to say that this limit does not exist, as I cannot divide by zero. Is this a correct assumption? And can I then conclude that the given limit does not exist?

Comment: What do you know about limits in one variable? Can you use L'Hôpital's rule or Taylor expansions?

Comment: No, you cannot approach 0 along the y axis (your function is not defined there), but the limit is still zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, note that
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x\,y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\sqrt\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\,y^2=0
$$
because the square root is bounded. Then you can use the Taylor expansion of the $\sin$:
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{1}{x}\sin\frac{x\,y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{1}{x}\frac{x\,y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\sqrt\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}\,y=0
$$
since again the root is bounded.

To explain that apparently the limit does not exist because you cannot approach the origin by $x=0$, note that the limit when $x\to 0,y\ne 0$ *does* exist. So the extension by continuity of $f$ (considering only the variable $x$ and a constant $y\ne 0$) is well defined at any point but $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you! I used polar coordinates and came to the same conclusion, but I love the elegance of this way.